# In HTML, how do I select all images from a folder to be shown in img src

Tags: html

Rather than listing a bunch of image sources, how do I just select all images in a folder.

Current HTML code looks like this...

```
<div class="gallery-grid">

    <img class="gallery-img" src="Images/img0.jpeg">
    <img class="gallery-img" src="Images/img1.jpeg">
    <img class="gallery-img" src="Images/img2.jpeg">
    <img class="gallery-img" src="Images/img3.jpeg">
    <img class="gallery-img" src="Images/img4.jpeg">
    <img class="gallery-img" src="Images/img5.jpeg">

</div>
```

Is there a way I can avoid listing each individual jpeg and just select all that are in a folder?

Thanks

Comment: Which folder are you referring to in your question?

Comment: You would need to create the img elements in a programming language on the web server (unless, as pointed out by Justinas, the directory is browseable). Do you know what is available on your web server?

Comment: With HTML only - no way

Comment: I don't have a web server. All I have is an html file. The website isn't hosted or anything yet. It's literally just an html file